# Number format exception in user input

Tags: java, android, exception, number-formatting

I have a **number format exception** when I try to compile my app. Here is the source of the error:

```
EditText a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPred_density);
        setPredDensity(Double.parseDouble(a.getText().toString()));
```

The problem is with the second line.

Here is the .xml file it is referring to in activity_main.xml:

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/etPred_density"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:hint="0.2"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
```

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="bham.eco"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ecologo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="bham.eco.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="bham.eco.Sequence"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.Sequence" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="bham.eco.Rules"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.Rules" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The error log:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: bham.eco, PID: 2543
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
    ... 11 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
    at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
    at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
    at bham.eco.MainActivity.assignParams(MainActivity.java:138)
    at bham.eco.MainActivity.playit(MainActivity.java:123)
    at bham.eco.MainActivity.runit(MainActivity.java:63)
    ... 14 more
```

What am I doing wrong here? The exception seems to be caused by the parseDouble() method.

Comment: If the string in the edit text field isn't in valid double format it will throw that error. You may want to format your string or check for validity before you parse it as a double.

Comment: Are you entering a number into the text field or something different?

Comment: And, `""` isn't a valid double.

Comment: Just use an `if` statement to validate before parsing. :)

Comment: An alternative to prior validation of the input string is to catch and handle the NFE.

Comment: @Zach I am entering a decimal point number into it but there is a default value set of 0.2 anyway. Should I just surround with try catch or check if (a != "")   ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
EditText a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPred_density);
String densityValue = a.getText().toString();
Double density = null;
 try
 {
      density = Double.parseDouble(densityValue);
 }
 catch(NumberFormatException e)
 {
     //Not a number, need to handle this
 }
 // Free to carry on with density
 setPredDensity(density);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, I will use it as it works, the user cannot enter anything but numbers anyway but thanks for the extra help @JosefE.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Regex` to check for `Double` format:

---

```
EditText a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPred_density);
String densityValue = a.getText().toString();

Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(densityValue);
boolean isDouble = matcher.matches();

if(isDouble) { 
    setPredDensity(Double.parseDouble(densityValue));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all we have to do this kind of operation in try catch block..
then add any logic..

Something like

```
    try{
        // logic

    }catch(Exception e){

       e.printStackStrace();
   }
```

So it can handle if any wrong data will appear in parsing like Josef said..

Answer (score 1):

Try check if:

- Its **null**
- Its **empty**
- Its **really an double**

  ```
  EditText a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPred_density);
  if (a.getText().toString().isEmpty() || a.getText() == null) 
  {
     doubleValueInvalid();
  }
  try
  {
      setPredDensity(Double.parseDouble(a.getText().toString()));
  }
  catch(NumberFormatException error){  //if its not double
      doubleValueInvalid();
  }
  ```

Look on Oracle Documentation what parseDouble Throws:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

Just check

```
 EditText a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPred_density);
    if (!a.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            setPredDensity(Double.parseDouble(a.getText().toString()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `a.getEditableText()` instead of setPredDensity(Double.parseDouble(`a.getText().toString())`);